# How to sort an array of documents, get its contents and its length in mongodb aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Assume I have a schema like shown below:

```
user = {
    id:'an id'
    username: 'some username'
}
post = {
    id:'an id'
    creater: 'some user id'
    postText: 'some text'
}
comment = {
    id:'an id'
    idOfPostThisCommentBelongsTo: 'some id'
    idOfCommenter: 'some id',
    commentText: 'some text' 
}
```

Below is my mongodb via mongoose aggregate function:

```
Post.aggregate([
        {$match:{"_id" : 'idOfThePost'}},
        {$lookup:{from:"users",localField:"creater",foreignField:"_id",as:"userWhoCreatedThisPost"}},
        {$unwind:"$userWhoCreatedThisPost"},
        {$lookup:{from:"comments",localField:"_id",foreignField:"idOfPostThisCommentBelongsTo",as:"comments"}},

        // unwind, sort by date, grouping them back
        {$unwind: {
            "path": '$comments',
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
        }},
        {$sort: {'comments.createdAt': -1}}, 
        {$group: {
            _id: '$_id', 
            postText:{$first: '$postText'},
            //how can I get the length of the comments' array????
            'comments': {$push: '$comments'}
        }}, 

        // without the group pipeline this is how I can get the number of comments(see below)
        // but when I try using the group pipeline(above) and project pipeline(below) 
        // and the aggregation doesn't work 
        {$project:{
            numberOfComments:{$size:'comments'},
        }}
```

I have been able to get the comments and even sort them by date. But I am stuck trying to 
get the length of all comments.

I am aware I can use `$first` to get the values of the previous
document. I have tried comments: `{$first: {$size: $comments}}` but it doesn't work.

How can I get the size of the comments array, while still sorting the array by date, while still getting the values of the post and user documents? 
(see below for example)

```
{
    _id: 5e5faae00e77ab07f0a7c661,
    userWhoPostedThePost: 'object with user details'
    postText: 'post text',
    comments: [ // sorted by date in descending order
              { /** comment content*/},
              { /** comment content*/}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically can change your group to sum 1 every time he found a comment. Something like this:

```
$group: {
    _id: '$_id', 
    'comments': {$sum: 1}
}
```